# problem while creating a filepath using variables

Tags: python, file, variables, filepath

I want to create a filepath using a variable i want to do it like this

```
import os
import gettitle as gt
def convert_file(
oldfilelocation = 'C:/Muziek' + (gt.finalyoutubetitle) + '.m4a'
newfilefilelocation = 'C:/Muziek' + (gt.finalyoutubetitle) + '.mmp3'
os.rename(r(oldfilelocation),r(newfilelocation))
)
exit()
```

But if i do this is get a lot of errors shown below.

[image]

Comment: In the method parenthesis, you put parameter and lines of code `os.rename(r(oldfilelocation)`, that isn'tpossible. You don't code between the method parenthesis

Comment: r is to rename the file

Comment: Do you mayby know a different way to convert m4a to mp3

Comment: r needs to rename the file

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is

- 2 method parameters `oldfilelocation` and `newfilelocation`, with default value
- 1 statement

```
def convert_file(oldfilelocation='C:/Muziek' + (gt.finalyoutubetitle) + '.m4a',
                 newfilelocation='C:/Muziek' + (gt.finalyoutubetitle) + '.mmp3'):
    os.rename(oldfilelocation, newfilelocation)
```